# Cast type within LINQ .include expression C# - ICollection to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

Im not sure if this question makes sense. But does anyone know if it is possible to typecast within an .include expression in a LINQ lambda expression.

```
var Items = _context.Items
        .Include(c => c.ItemCategorys)
        .ToList();

The navigation property is declared like an ICollection "public ICollection<ItemCategory> ItemCategorys { get; set; }"
```

The question is, can I cast the ICollection type to an IEnumerable within the ".include" statement.

I have tried this without success

---

```
var Items = _context.Items
        .Include(c => c.ItemCategorys.AsEnumerable())
        .ToList();
```

and

```
var Items = _context.Items
        .Include(c => c.ItemCategorys as IEnumerable<ItemCategorys>)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: no. the `Include` only exists to tell EF *which field* should be included. you _can not, should not, and do not want to_ do any type casting at this point. but how about you share the *actual problem* you are trying to solve by this? ***why*** are you doing all that?

Comment: No, the include is just telling EF to do a join and populate the contents into the Navigation Property, casting that doesn't make any sense.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I usually pass collection data to views (MVC) in the form of IEnumerable because I dont need all the methods available in a List fx, I only want to iterate over data, and have no use for .add, remove, count and such.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what include is supposed to be used for.

According to the specifications, [QueryableExtensions.Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.include?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) will include the complete specified property. Quite often people use it as a shorthand for "select all properties".

Suppose you have a simple one-to-many relation of between Schools and Students: every School has zero or more Students, every Student attends exactly one School, namely the School that the foreign key refers to.

If School [110] has 2000 Students, then every Student of School[10] will have a foreign key with a value 10. If you use Include to fetch School [10] with its Students, you will transfer this same value 10 more than 2000 times. What a waste of processing power!

It would be much wiser to use Select to fetch the data:

```
var schools = dbContext.Schools.Select(school => new
    {
        // Select only the School properties that you plan to use
        Id = school.Id,
        Name = school.Name,
        ...

        Students = school.Students.Select(student => new
        {
            // again: only the properties that you plan to use
            Id = student.Id,
            Name = student.Name,
            ...

            // not needed, you know the value
            // SchoolId = student.SchoolId,
        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

> In Entity framework always use Select to query data and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use include if you plan to change the fetched data.

Don't use Include to safe you some typing.

The nice thing about Select is that you can return data that differs from your source data which is exactly what you want.

You want to fetch "several properties of Items, each item with an enumerable sequence of several properties of its ItemCategories"

```
var result = dbContext.Items.Select(item => new
{
    Id = item.Id,
    Name = item.Name,
    ...

    ItemCategories = item.ItemCategories.Select(category => new
    {
        Id = category.Id,
        ...
    });
})
```

Note that ItemCategories is an IQueryable of some anonymous type. If you want it to be `IEnumerable<ItemCategory>`, use `.Select(category => new ItemCategory` and fill only the properties that you plan to use.

The result is an `IQueryable<ItemCategory>`.

- Positive: if your caller only wants a few ItemCategories you won't have fetched all of them.
- Negative: you'll have to keep the dbContext alive until all desired elements are fetched.

Problem is that users won't know which properties you have fille and which not. To overcome this, people tend to separate the internal data structure (= your classes in the DbSet) from the data that you expose to others:

```
.Select(category => new ExternalCategory()
{
     Id = category.Id,
     ...
});
```

The nice thing about this method is that you can give different users access to different values: some users get data with only get properties, others have methods to update the data and super users have access to change tables.

Also: by decoupling the database structure from the data that others can access, you'll be able to make small changes to the database without having to change the users.

Comment: I cant seem to get that syntax to work, I dont get the select statement available inside a select. Do you know of a more elaborate article explaining this.

Comment: btw. this is on EF6 6.4.0 MVC

Comment: What does visual studio say about the type of `item.Categories`? That should be an enumerable sequence

Comment: Visual studio says the type is a class, not an enumerable

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I think I was getting it wrong, I was trying the many to one lookup, which ends up in a class, your suggesten with the many to one works with the code you suggested.

Have you got a suggestion for the many to one syntax? I mean where one item can only have one category?

Comment: var dataresult2 = _context.Items
    .Select(item => new
    {
    Name = item.ItemName,
    ItemCategory = new
    {
    item.ItemCategory.ItemCategoryName,
    item.ItemCategory.ItemCategoryDescription
    }
    })
    .ToList();